# What is EXEC_PAJA/.#Misya extracting?

Tags: ar-tonelico

So i got all the Ar Tonelico Soundtracks in the mail and going though them i can ID the Songs that are downloaded into Aurica, Misha and Shurelia as they all have the prefix EXEC_ (ie. EXEC_CHRONICLE_KEY is the song Misha sings to seal Mir, EXEC_SUSPEND is what Shurelia uses to shut down Ar Tonelico and EXEC_RE_NATION is the song sang to restart it)

I got the soundtracks so i could listen to the boss music for when one fights ELMA_DS at the SPU and i found the track in the Soundtrack *Singing the Stars ~Hoshiyomi~ Ar Tonelico Hymmnos concert Side Ao* and it has EXEC_CHRONICLE_KEY and EXEC_HARMONIUS but the song i was looking for is titled *EXEC_PAJA/.#Misya extracting*

From the looks of the track name it seems like it's supposed to be Song Magic but if it is Song Magic who's it is and what does it do? because i don't remember there being a mention of a Song/Hymn Crystal called Paja.

Comment: All the examples where a Reyvateils sings a Hymmnos Extract and then uses Song Magic in battle (having Misha in the battle party when she sings the Purger or Harmonius, Luca using Song Magic while she sings EXEC_METAFALICA/., Cloche singing METHOD_REPLEKIA/. while singing any song magic during battle, Jakuri singing EXEC_HARMONIOUS_FUSION/. while also using Song Magic in the battle against Zodom, and also she using Song Magic while singing EXEC_DESPEDIA/.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXEC_PAJA is in fact the Hymn Crystal Purger, which was the overall plot to Phase 1. In  *Chanting the Moon ~Tsukikanade~ Ar Tonelico Hymmnos concert Side Kurenai* there is a track called *EXEC_PAJA/.#Orica extracting*.

Orica sounds very much like how Aurica's name is pronounced so one can assume that Misya is supposed to be Misha (they sound much the same as well). Also listening to *EXEC_PAJA/.#Orica extracting* sounds much like the music that plays when one battles ELMA_DS the first time and the music in the background is supposed to be the Reyvateil Purger was downloaded into sing to prevent ELMA_DS escaping into the Binary Field.

So *EXEC_PAJA* is the song from the Hymn Crystal Purger and *.#Misya extracting* indicates it's Misha's version of it. The reason she sings it is so that ELMA_DS won't flee. Just how Misha is singing that and the healing song at the same time is unknown as to my knowledge they can only sing one song at a time.

This is also backed up in [EXEC_PURGER's Wikia page](http://artonelico.wikia.com/wiki/EXEC_PURGER) where the fourth paragraph says

> Also known by the name **EXEC_PAJA/**.

The page also lists the unaltered names for both songs matching that of the tracks on the soundtracks, more than likely bring the untranslated romaji from the Japanese Version.

Comment: Also, Reyvateils can sing multiple songs at a time because singing Song Magic doesn't actually depend on their vocal cords: they just focus on the feeling forming the Song and the Tower does the rest of the work of providing the vocals and instrumentation. Also, Misya is Misha's original Japanese name, while Orica is Aurica's.

Comment: @aquagon i don't believe i have came across a situation where a Reyvateil is sings more than 1 song magic in the first 2 games (so it could be something in one of the other 3 games) unless you count Song Evolution but i assumed it's a different song when it changes. could you indicate where it's been documented (in game or in extened canon material) when a single Reyvateil sings 2 songs at the same time?